# javascript: <body onload=""> and window.onload

Tags: javascript, onload-event

I ran across a weird error today. I had a simple userscript which was adding a `window.onload` event to all the sites. But one of the sites had a `<body onload="func();">` defined. What happened is that `window.onload` was working as usual but `<body onload="">` stopped working for the site after installing userscript.

When I used `window.body.onload` instead both worked well. I know that `window.onload` and `<body onload="">` are different way of doing the same thing but what is happening in `window.body.onload` which makes it work well with `<body onload="">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Myforwik said, the event you hook up with `window.onload = ...;` is the same event you hook up with `<body onload="...">`. It's the `window` `load` event. Both of those ways of hooking it are in the old DOM0 style, which has been obsolete for some time. If you specify both, the latter one will win, knocking out the former. The same is true if multiple scripts set `window.onload` independently.

To avoid these sorts of issues, use DOM2-style event hookup:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    // DOM2 standard
    window.addEventListener("load", handler, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    // Microsoft's precursor to it, IE8 and earlier
    window.attachEvent("onload", handler);
}
else {
    // Some pre-1999 browser
    window.onload = handler;
}

function handler() {
}
```

Multiple DOM2 handlers can be attached to the same event, so multiple unrelated scripts can subscribe to it. Also, DOM2 handlers happily co-exist with DOM0 handlers.

So if you update your userscript to use the above, the `<body onload="...">` page will be unaffected.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fe6jL/5/ - this shows only one `alert` on running the script.

Comment: @ShiVik: Again, jsFiddle is wrapping all of your script in an `onload` handler (look at the drop-downs on the left), which obviously means by the time your script runs, the event has already happened. You need to choose one of the "no wrap" options from the drop-down, or for a tool that hides less from you, use http://jsbin.com. Also, when using `addEventListener`, note how you use the string `"load"`, **not** `"onload"` as you do with `attachEvent` (see my example above; you changed it in your fiddle). AND, avoid `alert` for event-related stuff. Working example: http://jsbin.com/agubat

Answer (score 2):

Window.onload and body tag's onload are the **same event**. So if you set the same event twice by two different methods it will only end up with the one value - one of the functions.

window.body.onload is a seperate event. Just another quirk of the DoM and what broswers do with it.

Comment: I tested here http://jsfiddle.net/fe6jL/1/ and it seems that `window.body.onload` get triggered after `<body onload>`

Comment: `@Myforwik`: I've never heard of `window.body.onload` and neither IE (tested 6 and 9) nor Chrome nor Firefox nor Opera seems to fire it: http://jsbin.com/ojibeq Did you mean `document.body.onload`? If so, as far as I can tell, it's the same as `window.onload` (at least when you use DOM0 handlers): http://jsbin.com/izalik

Comment: @ShiVik: Your test has an error, not least because jsfiddle is wrapping things for you. The code `window.body.onload = alert("hello");` **calls** `alert("hello")` and assigns its **return value** to `window.body.onload`. Try this: http://jsbin.com/izalik